# ubuntu14.04 build android4.4 modem error

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu-14.04, android-4.4-kitkat, dcmtk

when I build modem file it said: 
make:

```
[build/ELINK82_TB_KK_HSPA/DEFAULT/bin/dep/codegen_dep/nvram_auto_gen.det] Error 2
```

I user `gcc 4.4` and `g++ 4.4` build `android 4.4` modem, If anybody can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this problem by myself:
At first reinstall Ubuntu 10.04，and install all software below
sudo apt-get install openssh-server //安装ssh

sudo apt-get install git-core gawk

sudo apt-get install libxau-dev libxdmcp-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xtrans-dev libxcb1-dev

sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg zip curl libc6-dev libx11-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc

sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-jdk

sudo aptitude install -y bison g++-4.4 g++-4.4-multilib gcc-4.1-multilib gcc-4.4-multilib gcc-multilib m4 vim vim-runtime system-config-kickstart nmon ethtool tofrodos

sudo apt-get -y install libxml-simple-perl perl-doc libwww-perl libfile-spec-perl